# Remote desktop from Windows 7 does not remember login credentials

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm remote desktoping from a Windows 7 machine to another Windows 7 machine. The login popup has a checkbox "Remember my credentials".

Even though I checked this box, the next time I logged in, I had to re-enter my password.

Any idea why, and how to persist my credentials?

Answer (score 3):

Solved!
I've accidentally checked a checkbox in the "Options" tab of Remote Desktop login screen, labeled "Always ask for credentials".

Answer (score 2):

The server has the option of refusing cached credentials.  Try it from a different machine or login to verify it isn't the server.